# how can i install oem driver for micromax q331

Tags: android, eclipse, driver

Which driver is needed to test Android apk file (eclipse environment) on android phone (Micromax Q331)

1. driver for flashing firmware or
2. driver for normal connection

Answer (score 0):

I found this, not sure about the source. Try to search for a chipset driver.

https://androidmtk.com/install-spreadtrum-usb-driver-manually

Answer (score 0):

To test(DEBUG/GETTING LOGS), you need ADB connection between your device and computer. For ADB connection you need ADB driver of your device.

You can find ADB driver here:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip